# How to use one angularjs app in a different web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have made an angularjs app and I want to use it in another web application (eg. C# .Net,JAVA). I have another web app (which does not use angularjs) and when I click a button it should be redirected to my angularjs app to use the functionalities. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Which technology that another web application is created with?

Comment: C# .NET. It would help also if I know how to do it in a Java application.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Upvote and mark as answer if yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, for C# Web App, you can use `RedirectPermanent("<AngularJsApplicationFeaturePageUrl>")`; spend time in AngularJs application and when it completes, AngularJs Web Application is responsible for redirecting us to appropriate page in C# Web App.

For Example,

1. You might have experienced it in e-commerce apps. For buying\ checking-out items, you will be redirected to Bank's fund transfer page. When you are done, Bank website will redirect you to original e-commerce app.
2. You are seeing in Identity Module Providers like **Azure Active Directory**, **Google Single Sign On**,.. redirects you to its login page to challenge your identity and posts you back to original website.

You can find a ton of examples for above use cases.